# Swift 1.2 to swift 2: Cannot convert value of type to expected argument type

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, swift2, xcode7

I'm trying to create a NSURLSession task based on a tutorial I found online (https://www.raywenderlich.com/85528/user-accounts-ios-ruby-rails-swift#next_section) and I am getting the following error:

> Cannot convert value of type '(NSData!, NSURLResponse!, NSError!) -> ()' to expected argument type '(NSData?, NSURLResponse?, NSError?) -> Void

at this block of code:

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) in
```

The function where the issue belongs to can be found here

```
func sendRequest(request: NSURLRequest, completion:(NSData!, NSError!) -> Void) -> () {
// Create a NSURLSession task
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) in
  if error != nil {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
      completion(data, error)
    })

    return
  }

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
    if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
      if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
        completion(data, nil)
      } else {
        var jsonerror:NSError?
        if let errorDict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error:&jsonerror) as? NSDictionary {
          let responseError : NSError = NSError(domain: "HTTPHelperError", code: httpResponse.statusCode, userInfo: errorDict as? [NSObject : AnyObject])
          completion(data, responseError)
        }
      }
    }
  })
}
```

The full code block can be found here (https://codeshare.io/uJPcX) at line 68.

Comment: try change `data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!` to `data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?`

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you @Fonix

Comment: no problem :), you should look up how optional variables work to fully understand the difference between ! and ? in swift, also using any of those parameters later on will probably require a ! after them (and some null checks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

`data:NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!`

to

`data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?`

when using `data` or `response` etc further down you may have to write is as `data!` to unwrap the variable, but be careful because if the variable is `nil` it will crash, so you must check that it is not nil first